# Deploy a war of Spring Boot application to the local Tomcat server: 404 response

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I generated a simple [Greeting](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) web application using [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and choose `war` as the packaging type. Starting it from the terminal with `mvn spring-boot:run` and pointing my browser to `http://localhost:8080/greeting` returns the expected response.

I followed this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy) for the deployment steps and modified `pom.xml` so that to avoid including version numbers in the generated war:

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
...
</build>
```

I build the war as usual with `mvn clean install`and got the expected `demo-spring-web.war` which I copied/pasted inside the `apache-tomcat-10.0.4/webapp` folder.

Then I started the Tomcat bu running `catalina.sh run` from the Tomcat `bin` folder.
Tomcat started and displayed the `demo-spring-web.war` to be successfully deployed:

```
11-Apr-2021 18:24:36.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR 
Deployment of web application archive [/Users/serguei/soft/apache-tomcat-10.0.4/webapps/demo-spring-web.war] has finished in [1,286] ms
```

But when I tried to access the deployed application at `localhost:8080/demo-spring-web/greeting`, it returned 404 status.

What's wrong with that?

Comment: try just http://localhost:8080/greeting

Comment: Even if it is totally non-sense, I already tried it and without success, - every deployed app is running in its own context, that's why you should always prefix a route with the app name if you didn't tweak some Tomcat settings.

Comment: Spring's `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` is silently ignored by Tomcat 10, which looks for a `jakarta.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`.

Comment: Thanks a lot to @PiotrP.Karwasz,  downgrading the Tomcat version to `9.0.45` version fixed the problem. Damned :).

Comment: Well, Oracle's refusal to allow Jakarta EE to retain the `javax.*` namespace is causing thousands of hours of frustration to those, which don't follow Java EE news too often.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare a run class that extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`, for deploy in war mode.Like this :

```java
@SpringBootApplication public class AppTomcat extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. The default prepared/initialized application from spring initializer contains main() method initializing the application so that it can run in a stand alone mode and can be tested quickly.
   In case you want to deploy it to another container you should make a servlet initializing the application.

So you should be extending the class having main method with SpringBootServletInitializer and remove main method.

2. The "mvn clean package" will fail if you have plugin "org.springframework.boot" in the .

I think following above two steps will make the built war deployable in external tomcat.

I had read an article some times back, may be that can also help: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy